# How to fix "The connection was not closed, The connection's current state is open."

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

Whenever I click the delete button on my webpage I always recive the "The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.", However I already closed the connection.

```
 protected void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM [Table] where [Id] ='"+Id.Text+"'", con);
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "alert('Successfully Deleted');", true);

            disp_data();
        }
```

I even tried to change

```
con.Close();
```

to

```
con.Dispose();
```

but I ended up with the same error

Comment: It looks like you are keeping one connection and using that for all purposes. Don't do that. Create a new connection when you need it, and please use the using pattern.

Comment: I think it is better to use `using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
}` when using block close connection automatically close.

Comment: Learn to properly and securely parameterize your SQL queries. Your code is open to SQL injection.

Comment: You also shouldn't mix UI and data access in the same class. Tying them together makes it difficult to swap out either one, or to independently test. Move your data access to a new class (look up the Repository pattern).

Answer (score 3):

You might think it's expensive to create new connections all the time. It's not, there is connection pooling built-in and the connections will actually be reused. Therefore you should do something like this:

```cs
protected void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM [Table] where [Id] ='"+Id.Text+"'", connection)
        { 
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "alert('Successfully Deleted');", true);
        disp_data();
}
```

The using pattern takes care of closing and disposing both SqlConnection and SqlCommand.
Next you should get rid of `con` as a class member and use this pattern althrough your code.